# SSRS horizontal range bar with outside label

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm working in SSRS 2008 range bar. I need to plot the series label out side of the graph like the below fig.

[image]

But when i try to plot the label out side of the bar it is displayed left side of the graph. Please help any one
Thanks in advance

My series property window is look like.

[image: this]

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to click on the `Chart Series`.

**Image 1**:

[image: Example]

In the properties windwos, you should be able to see the properties of **`Chart Series`**.

Scroll down to **`CustomAttributes`** and then go to **`LabelStyle`** Property.

From here you can choose the style that suits your requiremnts.

[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But there is no label property in my CustomAttributes. There is a BarLabelStyle with 4 options outside,left,center and right. I tried this and also the Label and SmartLabel properties. But its not working.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show what you are actually talking about?

Comment: After trying different options, did you try exporting the report to PDF etc to see how that looks? Sometimes the report viewer just doesn't display the outcome of charts perfectly but after export, they totally take the different shape.

Comment: I tried to exporting the report to PDF, but the result has no change. The label is always on the left of the bar.